# How do I include a tarball or svn dependency in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, egg, pypi

I have a project that has python-xlib as a requirement. Unfortunately python-xlib is not on pypi, so in my requirements file I use:
svn+https://python-xlib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/python-xlib/tags/xlib_0_15rc1/ as per this advice:
[How do you install Python Xlib with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054745/how-do-you-install-python-xlib-with-pip)

This works fine with pip, but I want to package it with setup.py. Only actual eggs are allowed in install_requires, so this answer:
[How can I make setuptools install a package that's not on PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi)
suggests using dependency_links, which I did.

svn+https did not work in a dependency_link, so instead I link to the tarball referenced from this page: http://python-xlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-xlib/tags/xlib_0_15rc1/
. This tarball gets downloaded the way I expect it to, but when it is time to install it, I get:

```
Searching for pyxlib
Best match: pyxlib [unknown version]
Downloading http://python-xlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-xlib/tags/xlib_0_15rc1/?view=tar#egg=pyxlib
Processing xlib_0_15rc1
error: /tmp/easy_install-BDFVH3/xlib_0_15rc1/COPYING: Not a directory
```

I don't get it. Of course COPYING is not a directory. Why does setuptools (or is it distutils?) not run the setup.py that is in the python-xlib root? I suspect this must all be quite easy. How do I include python-xlib as a dependency for my egg?

Comment: I think it's Sourceforge messing with things. Has happened before. Here is a related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646110/including-direct-dependency-download-links-in-setup-py I think the answer is you cannot include direct dependency links in eggs. You need to use buildout or PIP requirements file.