# How can I stop pyautogui from printing <class 'Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, pyautogui

First time asking here, so I hope someone has an answer for me.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, and using pyautogui for the first time.

From the terminal I have just only imported pyautogui, and get the output of:

`<class 'Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension>`

When I run pyautogui inside of a python(2.7.6) file, this line is always output to the terminal.  Is there anyway to stop pyautogui from printing this line to the terminal?

```
import pyautogui

def someFunction():
    ....
    return x&o's

someFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what OS you are running, but I am running **Linux** and was able to solve that issue, by installing the required packages from the documentation
"On Linux, PyAutoGUI requires **python-xlib (for Python 2)** or python3-Xlib (for Python 3) module installed."

## Following this guys answer

```
sudo pip install svn+https://svn.code.sf.net/p/python-xlib/code/trunk/
```

[How do you install Python Xlib with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055013/4237323)

I ran that because with the regular pip install pyautogui was not sufficient. See Below with code being inputs and yellow being outputs

```
import  PIL
from PIL import Image
import pyautogui
```

> Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension

```
import pyautogui
```

> 

Hope that helps!