# Error with ursina: "No module named Xlib"

Tags: python, ursina

I'm trying to use Ursina to make a game. I installed it on my Ubuntu/Debian terminal using "pip install ursina". It seemed to install fine, but any time I try to run anything using ursina, I get this error message:
[image]

I'm quite confused and I've tried uninstalling / reinstalling it a few times, but to no avail. Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't know why they didn't list that as a dependency.  Try `pip install python3-xlib`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054745/how-do-you-install-python-xlib-with-pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved with:

```
pip install python3-xlib
```